# Is there any way to limit access to "PageSpeed Insight" to only those from japan?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I am using PageSpeed Insights from Japan, but it seems to be evaluated as an access from overseas.
Until 11/27, it was displayed as access from Japan, but after 11/28, it is displayed as access from overseas.The PageSpeed Insights image showed the difference because I could see the popups of access from overseas.

Is there any way to limit access to "PageSpeed Insight" to only those from japan?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to choose the location from which PSI runs. It typically runs in a datacenter near you, but that can vary based on where your request ends up being served, which depends on network conditions, the particular datacenter workload, etc.

I don't believe the report is ever as specific with location as country level, however. Did it possibly say "Browser location: Asia" before?

The [PSI FAQ has a brief entry](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about#what-device-and-network-conditions-does-lighthouse-use-to-simulate-a-page-load) about this:

> PageSpeed also runs in a Google datacenter that can vary based on network conditions. You can check the location that the test was by looking at the Lighthouse Report's environment block (one of: North America, Europe, or Asia)

It's possible the location will eventually revert to wherever it was running before. In the meantime, you can get close to the same experience as the PSI lab tests but from exactly where you are by [running Lighthouse locally](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/#get-started).